# How to build FFmpeg Executable binary for Android on Mac OS?

Tags: android, build, ffmpeg, binary

I'm a new beginner with `FFmpeg`. All I need is `FFmpeg` **executable binary for Android**. I followed the great tutorial from [roman10.net](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

Here is my **build_android.sh** file:

```
    #!/bin/bash
NDK=/Users/sunshine/Documents/android-ndk-r11-linux-x86_64
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --enable-libmp3lame\
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

The tutorial says:

> Once it’s done, you should be able to find a folder
> $NDK/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.1/android

In my case, the build process is done, but I don't see any android folder. Some new files are created in the same folder with **build_android.sh** file. Where is my mistake?

Comment: did you get this working?

Comment: @H.Brooks I had to use Ubuntu for building ffmpeg execute file

Comment: thank you for the reply, I just got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and later solved after changing the NDK path. For example instead of

```
NDK=/Users/sunshine/Documents/android-ndk-r11-linux-x86_64
```

you can try

```
NDK=$HOME/Documents/android-ndk-r11-linux-x86_64
```

However I can't guarantee if this is the exact problem with your setup.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same "problem", but I found the files in: $NDK/sources/android/arm (lib and include directories).

I hope it helps!